# what is the deep link of telegram bots to share texts?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

there is a deep link that user can share some text with her friends or chats.
I just know this deep link:

```
https://telegram.me/ExampleComBot?start=vCH1vGWJxfSeofSAs0K5PA
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this format

`http://t.me/share/url?url=<URL>&text=<TEXT>`

e.g., `http://t.me/share/url?url=blog.sean.taipei%2F2016%2F10%2Ftelegram-bot&text=Hello+World!` is [this](http://t.me/share/url?url=blog.sean.taipei%2F2016%2F10%2Ftelegram-bot&text=Hello+World!)

Comment: Where can I get reference about query params for the `http://t.me/share/url` URL?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these formats will work, but the first one is recommended by the official documentation...

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
tg://msg_url?url={url}&text={text}
```

**The Official API Documentation Source: [Core.Telegram.org: Widgets -> Sharing Button](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons)**

You may share:

- `url` : The URL you want to share.
- `text` : Text to accompany the URL you want to share.

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#telegramme

[image: Social Share URLs]